# How to deploy app_browsers file?

Tags: deployment, browsers

Is there a simple way to deploy a file into the `App_Browsers` folder of all web applications?

By now, the only way I found is to use a feature receiver that create and fire a custom SPTimerJob that put the file in all web applications...

This works but it looks like rather complicated.

Comment: Why are you deploying an app_browsers file? Is it to register a control adapter?

Comment: yes, to be more precise, I'm overriding some native sharepoint controls using control adapters

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a solution where you register the control adapters programatically via an HTTP module. That way you can do all the necessary configuration via web.config and there are no deployment issues.

Have a look at this article if that sounds like a way to go: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27117/Programmatically-Setting-Control-Adapters-for-URL